# open trip planner scalibility (or an alternative library)

Tags: public, rails-routing, dijkstra, transport, gtfs

I am playing around with open trip planner novadays. Actually I will use some parts of the library like base public transportation functions, without bike, roads, streets, etc... functionality. I will only provide bus/subway stops, times, and routes information to the library.

As far as I understood OTP uses a Graph.obj file which could built from a custom route and street data. The process loads all the Graph.obj data into memory when application gets started.

**My concern is**; if I have a huge route data, then I will probably need to create a huge Graph.obj file from data itself. Then the process will load all the data into memory, and this will eat all my memory.

**Question;** Does OTP scalible? Are there any way to provide source data from a database? Or something already implemented in a database like mySql, postgreSql, etc..? And what are the other open source alternatives which I can scale my application?

Answer (score 6):

From the data point of view most of the open source routing library use the same approach: generation of a custom data-structure (e.g. file for OpenTripPlanner) and memory loading.

How big it is your map?

Anyway here are a couple of alternatives:

- http://graphhopper.com (in Java, very simple and lightweight)
- http://project-osrm.org (in C++, probably the fastest one)

Take a look also here:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers#comparison_matrix